# maya script editor: how to keep python code after execute

Tags: python, maya

see my gif, in script editor, I hope keep python code after code is executed and run it again next time, how should i do?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way is script editor > file > save script, i save script to test.py, script editor will create "test.py" tab, run code in this tab will not clear code after code is executed

Answer (score 0):

Myself I always select the code, then run it.

Selected text in the Script Editor will not be removed on execution. https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjc6j.jpg

Comment: Great answers both this and @chikadance's but seriously, having to either save as script or select all text before running is ... yeah. There must be a way to either run without code disappearing, or, retrieve back previous buffer of code such as in commandlines where you often can just use Up Arrow or similar to get the previous commands back.